# Spawner in visual studios shows no errors but isn't working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project in Unity (2018.4.9f1) where I want to have Objects spawn when I start the game. So I tried this code in Visual Studios (as shown below) but eventhough I'm pretty sure it should be working, it isn't. It doesn't even show me any errors.I attached the code to a Game Object and put the bool isPlayerGrounded to true, set the Spawn Counter to 30 but when I started the game, nothing happened.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int spawnCounter;
    public bool isPlayerGrounded = true;

    public void Start()
    {
        void Spawning()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < spawnCounter; i++)
            while(isPlayerGrounded)
            {
                GameObject newGo = new GameObject();
                Debug.Log("Something spawned" + spawnCounter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? What's the value of `isPlayerGrounded`?

Comment: I mean I didn't define its value so it should be "true", right? Since I just called it public bool isPlayerGrounded; If that's even what you were asking. If not, I'm sorry, I'm really new to coding.

Comment: Default value for a Boolean variable is false. So if you want it to be true then you should explicitly assign value to it by doing `isPlayerGrounded = true;` in `Spawning()` method. You should learn to debug the code and observe the values of variables at runtime.

Comment: Oh, thanks, good to know! I assigned "true" to it, it's unfortunately still not working. Yeah, I'll look up how to debug the code, thank you!

Comment: Can you update the code here which assigns the value to `isPlayerGrounded`?

Comment: is this what you meant? Just updating it in my question?

Comment: This code should spawn 30 empty gameObjects into your scene, you sure your script is attached to an active GameObject in the scene, and in the hieracrhy window you should see then 30 empty gameObjects

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing happens when you run the game is because you are not instantiating the GameObject you create.

When you do `GameObject newGo = new GameObject();` you need to do the following after:

```
Instantiate(newGo, Vector3.Zero, Quaternion.Identity);
```

This will spawn the newly created Object into your scene.

I'd suggest looking at this documentation to further understand the Instantiate method.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: Every time you call `new GameObject();` an empty gameObject is instantiated in the scene without the need of calling `MonoBehaviour.Instantiate();`